# Value in the name & website fields for my comments form

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I am getting values in the name and website fields of the comment form from the last submitted comment.
Earlier i had customized comment form. Initially it was working fine but after a day or two, had the same problem stated above in addition to a value for the email field also. And on submitting comments  was getting error please fill in the name and email.

So i deleted my comments.php and other functions from functions.php and switched back to the default comment form.

But i am still getting the value for name and website.

```
<div class="row aboutauthor">
                  <h5>About author:</h5>
                    <div class="row aboutauthortxt">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                      <div class="authorimage-wrapper">
                          <div class="author-img-bg"></div>
                          <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>/authorimg.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <h6>Article by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h6>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-9">
                    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>               


                 <?php comments_template('',true); ?>
```

Comment: Please show the code what was in the existing html/php file and in the new one

Comment: without your codes we cant say anything.

Comment: @Rajarshi Goswami  Now i am using just comments_template('',true);

Comment: Or are you asking for the code  initially i wrote in comments.php and in function.php